# Logging Configuration Apache HttpClient 5 on WIldfly

Tags: apache, logging, httpclient, wildfly

Having trouble turning off DEBUG logging for apache httpclient 5 on wildfly 10.1.  So far, I've done the following:

1. standalone.xml, under
2. logging.properties - documentation states that this only takes effect when wildfly is starting, so I didn't expect this to work:

   logger.org.apache.http.level=ERROR
   logger.org.apache.http.wire.level=ERROR
3. added java vm arguments:

   -org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog 
   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true 
   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=WARN 
   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire=WARN
4. Tried it via code:

   System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log","org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
   System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog","error");
   System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http","error");
   System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire","error");
   client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

No luck, on any of these.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of the log output?

Comment: 11:08:21,910 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) 11:08:21.910 [default task-2] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 756[\r][\n]"
11:08:21,911 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) 11:08:21.911 [default task-2] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
11:08:21,994 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) 11:08:21.994 [default task-2]

Comment: basically getting all the http.wire DEBUG lines.

Comment: Do you have a logging configuration file, log4j or a logging.properties, file in your deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - figured this out.  I was using SLF4J but had not configured it for wildfly see http://blog.anotheria.net/devops/enable-logback-in-jboss/.
In addition, I had to create: META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Without doing so, I got double timestamps in my log file:

```
11:08:21,910 INFO [stdout] (default task-2) 11:08:21.910 [default task-2] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire
```

Once SLF4J was configured correctly, modifying the JVM's logging.properties file works like a charm:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-2.b14.fc22.x86_64/lib/logging.properties
org.apache.http.level = SEVERE
org.apache.http.wire.level = SEVERE
```

Note that prior to configuring SLF4J correctly, *none* of the methods listed in the apache http client documentation worked.

Answer (score 0):

From my projects:

to hide warnings about invalid cookies, create custom config

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES).build();
httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
```

or disable logging completely

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: Hi -thanks for the input - tried this but did not work.